# is it possible to use jq to replace a value in one json file from a another dictionary json file?

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have two json file, one contains a map key name and a type, the other is a flat json file.

eg. first file contains something like this:

```
[ { "field": "col1", "type": "int" }, { "field" : "col2", "type" : "string" }]
```

second file is a large jsons object file separated by line break:

```
{ "col1":123, "col2": "foo"}
{ "col1":123, "col2": "foo"}
...
```

can I use JQ to generate an output json like this:

```
{ "col1":{ "int" : 123 }, "col2": { "string" : "foo"} }
{ "col1":{ "int" : 123 }, "col2": { "string" : "foo"} }

....
```

Comment: Check out `jq`'s `--slurpfile` option to easily consume your second file. It does half the work, but I'm too much of a newbie with `jq` to produce the second half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You might want to transform your first file in an easier to consume format first: map the `.type` to the `.field` properties to an object (to use as a dictionary)

```
reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.field] = $i.type)
```

Then you could go through your second file to use these mappings to update the values.  Use `--argfile` to read the contents of the first file into a variable.

```
$ jq --argfile file1 file1.json '
(reduce $file1[] as $i ({}; .[$i.field] = $i.type)) as $map
    | with_entries(.value = { ($map[.key]): .value })
' file2.json
```

which yields:

```
{
  "col1": {
    "int": 123
  },
  "col2": {
    "string": "foo"
  }
}
{
  "col1": {
    "int": 123
  },
  "col2": {
    "string": "foo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could use the --slurpfile option but your dictionary is already a single JSON entity (a JSON object in your case), so it would be simpler to read the dictionary using the --argfile option.

Assuming that:

- your jq filter is in a file, say `merge.jq`;
- your dictionary is in dictionary.json;
- your input stream is in input.json

the jq invocation would look like this:

```
jq -f merge.jq --argfile dict dictionary.json input.json
```

With the above, you would of course refer to the dictionary as $dict in merge.jq

(Of course you could specify the filter on the jq command line, if that's what you prefer.)

Now, over to you!